# Mongo DB logs showing hundreds of open connections without any running operations

Tags: mongodb

When I check my MongoDB logs (/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log), it shows something like:

```
end connection 127.0.0.1:57132 (**651 connections now open**)
```

But I am not running so many processes. How are so many connections open? Is there a way to close all these connections?

I do run a cron job (from shell script) to query mongodb every minute. Is that what is causing so many open connections? Should I close the connection every time after querying?

When I run `db.serverStatus().connections`, I get:

`{ "current" : 500, "available" : 319, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(1328754) }`

I think that's too big a number. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Mongo does not usually log information about connections unless they are somehow exceptional (in size of the results or time to perform them for instance). Is this a cluster? If so these connections are probably the normal result of the mongo boxes syncing to each other. If not try

```
netstat -ln|grep 27017
```

to see who's using your mongo.

Comment: The command outputs the following : 

`unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     343214389 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

I still see this log in mongodb :

` [conn1324029] end connection 127.0.0.1:52013 (613 connections now open)`

Comment: When I run `db.serverStatus().connections`, I get:

`{ "current" : 500, "available" : 319, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(1328754) }`

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons I have seen for high connection counts:

- When using replication
- The Java driver didn't close any connections one it had opened them. Could be controlled with a property

Comment: I am using Python to connect to Mongodb. I am creating a MongoClient in my script but not closing it explicitly. Should the mongodb client be killed explicitly?

Comment: When I run `db.serverStatus().connections`, I get:

`{ "current" : 500, "available" : 319, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(1328754) }`

Comment: I haven't used the Python client much, but I think in general you shouldn't close a connection unless your application is shutting down. The Java driver maintains a pool of connections it uses - perhaps the Python does the same?

Comment: Yes that's what I read in the docs too. But then why is the number of connections so high?